# Valid random generation algorithm or not?

Tags: random

```
long timeValue = timeInMillis();
int rand = timeValue%100 + 1;
```

If we execute the above code N times in a loop, it will generate N random numbers between 1 to 100. I know generation of random nos is a tough problem. Just wanted to know is this a good  random number generation algorithm? Or is it pseudo random number generator?

Why I think this will produce good estimate of random behavior?
1) all no from 1 to 100 will be uniformly distributed. There is no bias.
2) timeInMillis will show somewhat random behavior because we can never really guess at what time CPU will execute this function. There are so many different tasks running in CPU. So the exact time of execution of timeInMillis() instruction is not predictable in next iteration of loop.

Comment: "is this a good number random generation algorithm?" - No.

Comment: Lately figured out one more catch. Just wanted to point out. If execution of instruction is somewhat random, nos will not be uniformly distributed. So if 2) is true 1) can't be valid. If 1) is valid 2) can't be valid. So seems I am wrong in my reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For a start, on most processors, this will loop many times (probably the full 100) within 1 millisecond, which will result in 100 identical numbers.

Even seeding a random number generator with a timer tick can be dangerous - the timer tick is rarely as "random" as you might expect.

Comment: "For a start, on most processors, this will loop many times (probably the full 100) within 1 millisecond, which will result in 100 identical numbers."  This is the point I missed. Thanks for reminding - CPU cycle is in nanoseconds! So this point makes above code totally wrong. But for a moment assume that if CPU cycle is 1ms, then what would be your comments?

Comment: If you want a good but practical number generator, try the Mersenne Twister http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister . There are open source libraries implementing this for many languages, and I've successfully used it for numerical/computational (rather than cryptographic) random number generation.

Comment: @Sanjeev, it still wouldn't be random as the sequence would be something like 1,2,3; or 1,3,5,7; or slightly uneven due to sampling, eg. 1,5,10,14,19,24.  Knuth's Art of Computer Programming has a good chapter on randomness and testing randomness, although the actual algorithms are decidedly dated.

Comment: "Even seeding a random number generator with a timer tick can be dangerous - the timer tick is rarely as "random" as you might expect." Got this one also. Because the behavior will also depend when the next random no is computed. Because time is in increasing order. If I am computing this function after 100ms seconds, there is probability of getting same no each time. One more thing you already pointed out - nos may be in ascending order and this is not random. Thanks for clarifying. So now I know how bad this code is for random no :)

Comment: Yes the time from program start (or a timer event) to the seed setting is probably not random; and the program start might not be a completely random timer (depends on the OS). Also real time timer ticks do not necessarily increment in 1ms increments. Eg I think the old PCs and ATs increment in larger increments (18ms iirc).

Answer (score 1):

here is my suggestion to generate random numbers:

1- choose a punch of websites that are as far away from your location as possible. e.g. if you are in US try some websites that have their server IPs in malasia , china , russia , India ..etc . servers with high traffic are better.

2- during times of high internet traffic in your country (in my country it is like 7 to 11 pm) ping those websites many many many times ,take each ping result (use only the integer value) and calculate modulus 2 of it ( i.e from each ping operation you get one bit : either 0 or 1).

3- repeat the process for several days ,recording the results.

4- collect all the bits you got from all your pings (probably you will get hundreds of thousands of bits ) and choose from them your bits . (maybe you wanna choose your bits by using some data from the same method mentioned above :) )

BE CAREFUL : in your code you should check for timeout ..etc

Comment: plugging a microphone and reading from `/dev/audio` yields useful random bits too (albeit correlated).

Comment: @docesam this is good implementation. We are making a data set by collecting latency (random behavior based on traffic) of our requests. This data set coupled with time ticker approach increases randomness and removes the disadvantage of getting data in ascending order. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @Alexandre C Don't know much about this. We are collecting the random behavior of noise (which characteristic by the way?). Need to read further on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Sanjeev: Actually I used random noise from a microphone to get a good seed for a PRNG.

Comment: @Alexandre C We are using random noise for seed. Why not use random noise also to generate random nos. Why PRNG is required? Is it that after we set seed, the PRNG calculates the subsequent random nos very fast. While generating the random nos directly from /dev/audio (without using PRNG) is very slow. Correct?

Comment: @Sanjeev: The problem is that you have to investigate the correlation structure of your noise